# Trouble on eager loading and using the 'where' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, eager-loading

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.1. I am using the `includes` method and I would like to understand why when I call the `where` method on an eager loaded collection it reloads associated objects instead of just finding that object in the eager loaded collection. Since all related objects are already been eager loaded I expect that the `where` method does *not* hit the database to reload those objects!

That is, I have the following:

```
article_categories =
  article
    .categories
    .where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
    .includes(:comments)
```

If I run

```
# CASE 1:

article_categories.each do |article_category|
  article_category.comments.map(&:title)
end
```

eager loading works as expected: the "N + 1 query problem" is avoided. However, the above code returns also comment titles that have *not* "`:user_id == @current_user.id`", but I do not want to retrieve those ones at all.

So, since I thought that by using the eager loading I already get all comments, I used a further `where(:user_id => @current_user.id)` statement like in the following code:

```
# CASE 2:

article_categories.each do |article_category|
  article_category.comments.where(:user_id => @current_user.id).map(&:title)
end
```

However, in this case eager loading does *not* work as expected: the "N + 1 query problem" is *not* avoided... but comments have "`:user_id == @current_user.id`"!

*I would like to eager loading comments with "`:user_id == @current_user.id`" (**how can I make that by taking advantage from the eager loading?**) and I would like to understand why the `where` statement cancels eager loading effects.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case 1 the where clause only applies to categories. If you also want it to apply to comments you can do this:

```
article_categories =
  article
    .categories
    .includes(:comments)
    .where('categories.user_id = ? AND comments.user_id = ?', @current_user.id, @current_user.id)
```

Comment: The `where` method "refers to"/"runs on" `categories`, not on `comments`. Both, `categories` and `comments` have the `user_id` attribute/column.

Comment: So you need the where clause on both categories and comments?? What do you mean? Your question seems to be about the fact that there are comments that don't have `user_id == @current_user.id`. My answer fixes that.

Comment: I mean that I would like to retrieve all `categories.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)` and eager load all `article.comments.where(:category_id => category_ids, :user_id => @current_user.id)`. `category_ids` is the array of the mentioned `categories.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)`. *P.S.*: I do not know if I was clear.

Comment: "there are comments that don't have user_id == @current_user.id". Yes, it is.

Comment: I opened a more specific question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629860/trouble-on-eager-loading-second-degree-associated-objects.