# Trouble on eager loading "second degree" associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, eager-loading

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.1. I would like to eager loading "second degree" associated objects by applying some conditions, but I am in trouble.

It seems that I already solved [part of my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629046/trouble-on-eager-loading-and-using-the-where-method) by using:

```
article_categories =
  article
    .categories
    .includes(:comments => [:category_relationships])
    .where(:category_relationships => {:user_id => @current_user.id})
```

where involved classes are stated as the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_relationships
  has_many :comments,
    :through => :comment_relationships

  ...
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_relationships
  has_many :categories,
    :through => :category_relationships

  ...
end
```

The above code (it seems to do it right):

1. loads all `categories` by caring the `has_many :through` `:category_relationships` association (that is, by caring the `.where(:category_relationships => {:user_id => @current_user.id})` condition);
2. eager loads all `article.comments.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)`.

However, I would like to make some more:

1. to *order* retrieved `categories` by a `:position` attribute present in `category_relationships` so that the resulting `article_categories` are *ordered by position*;
2. to *eager load* also `category_relationship` objects where `user_id == @current_user.id` since the above code doesn't make that.

**How can I make that by taking advantage from the eager loading?**

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using two different join tables between `Category` and `Comment`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1. .order("category_relationships.position")
2. Imagine eager loading is cartessian product with some filtering so "where" is filtering the end result of include (left join really). But it can be done with `where` with subquery which first will filter categories by user then your where can be removed.

Comment: Can you provide some example?